# How to insert data from another table in MySQL when I have an index?

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc

This is a table(called project) where I want to insert some data into it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOZmb.png)

And this is a table(called channel) where I am ready to find some data on it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAuU3.png)

Now I have a sequence like `(name, maintainer, channelid, description,...)` to insert, but I need `channelname` in `channel` table. That means, I must first look at `channel` table, and get data, finally insert into `project` it.

Can I use only mysql sentence to insert which means I only to need `(name, maintainer, channelid, description,...)` insert into project table, and makes mysql **auto** generate the column `channelname`?
And when I update `channel` table `name` column, can it be **auto** updated in `project` table.

I am using JDBC, it makes a little complex to insert it, like what I said

> That means, I must first look at `channel` table, and get data, finally insert into `project` it.

Also updating `project` when `channel` table changed is complex.So I am finding only use mysql method to make it.(Sadly,I can only use mysql by jdbc like `jdbcTemplate.query("...")`, so I hope the answer could be in this way)
)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: why do you want channel name instead of channel id in project?  that's just going to lead to trouble

Comment: `INSERT INTO channel (id, name, type, creator, creatorEmail, score, due) VALUES (1, School, Thesis, ***, ***, 10, 2022-12-11 23:30:00');`
`INSERT INTO project (id, name, maintainer, channelid, channelname, description, company, money, submitdate, status, fig, zip) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
`

Comment: Becuase I need to show channel name, if only use channel id every time that will lead to a search in anther table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it as it:

```sql
UPDATE project
SET
  name =(
    SELECET name
    FROM
      channel
    WHERE
      channel.id = project.channelid
  ) 
WHERE
  project.channelid = channel.id;
```